# Is it possible to write a Laravel application that does not rely on __callStatic or Facade behavior?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm starting a fresh Laravel 4 application for the first time and one of the things I notice is that there is some magic going on when I follow the quick start guide.  It suggests things like this to set up routes:

> Route::get(...)

But when I went to find the static `get` function in the `\Illuminate\Routing\Route` class it wasn't there.  It seems to actually be calling `Illuminate\Routing\Router`.  I haven't dug into how it is calling this on the `Router` class yet.

But when I looked at the `Router` class's `get` function it's not static.  Following a stack trace it seems that it is going through some `Facade` classes that manage a singleton instance of the class, and then use `__callStatic` to call the instance methods.

Is it possible to write my code without taking advantage of some of these shortcuts?  My IDE is not able to follow these things very well so I lose autocomplete and function details.  I tried to instantiate a `Router` instance manually and call the `get` function dynamically but it did not seem to get hooked into the application and was ignored.  I would also like to explicitly include Laravel namespaces, but it seems to convert things like `Route` to `\Illuminate\Routing\Router` automatically, which I'm finding difficult to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible not to use Facades, but it's not recommended.

Instead, consider using an IDE helper such as https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: That is fantastic... wish they would add something like this into the core because without it I wouldn't feel quite as comfortable that I am writing valid code.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses the Facade pattern for convenience.  You can indeed write your app without using facades, but it will a bit more tedious.  The facades just access items on the App container, so if you look through the various service providers you can fetch what you need.